# Drawing in WM_MOUSEMOVE

Tags: c, windows, winapi, gdi

Good day,

What is best practice for drawing in mouse movement?
I see many examples (at MSDN also) when drawing is performed in WM_MOUSEMOVE.
But I think that better approach is all drawing in WM_PAINT.

Example:

**Version 1**

```
case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
{
     DummyFunctionForClientCoords();
     DummyFunctionForDrawing();
}
break;
```

**Version 2**

```
    case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
    {
         DummyFunctionForClientCoords();
         InvalidateRect(hwnd, &rc, TRUE); /* For sake of simplicity, update region is all area. */
    }
    break;

case WM_PAINT:
    {
         DummyFunctionForDrawing();
    }
    break;
```

Maybe this question is opinion based, but I want know advantages and disadvantages **Version 1** vs. **Version 2**.

Comment: What are you drawing when the mouse is moving?

Comment: You can draw whenever you like; the only rule is that your `WM_PAINT` handler needs to be able to recreate the entire display on demand. But note that `WM_PAINT` messages are only generated when there are no other messages in the queue, so unless you use `UpdateWindow` to force a redraw you'll get delayed feedback if the user is moving the mouse quickly.

Comment: (By the way, questions relating to "best practice" are generally off-topic for SO since they are primarily opinion based).

Comment: @Marius Bancila: This have nothing with question.

Comment: @Jonathan Potter: This make sense. Yes I know that is lightly off-topic, but Google in this thing is not friend. :-) OK. If I use UpdateWindow, is something else to must know? Because I want use double buffer in WM_PAINT, so is better for me use drawing in WM_PAINT.

Comment: `InvalidateRect(hwnd, &rc, TRUE);` will cause flicker, use `InvalidateRect(hwnd, &rc, FALSE);` instead

Comment: Unless you must support Windows XP, you should avoid using GDI in new code.

Comment: @MooseBoys: The question isn't even asking for rendering, less so for a particular rendering API. Besides, what technical rationale are you basing your ill-advised suggestion on? GDI is in the majority of cases the best API to use, both with respect to resource consumption as well as rendering speed.

Comment: @IInspectable The question has the tag [tag:gdi], and the recommended approach for where to put "drawing" code, how to handle `WM_PAINT` etc. is highly dependent on whether or not you're using it vs. one of its successors.

Comment: @MooseBoys: There is no successor to GDI. If you feel like using something like Direct2D, validation and invalidation of window regionss is still best left to the system. `WM_PAINT` and Direct2D can (and should) be used in conjunction. Regardless, there is no API replacement for GDI, and GDI is not deprecated. Again, in the majority of cases, GDI consumes less system resources while providing better performance.

Comment: @IInspectable [*Direct2D and DirectWrite are recommended for new programs*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff684176(v=vs.85).aspx). As far as memory consumption, GDI is plausibly more efficient for simple content; as far as performance and power consumption, it is generally not, especially for a case like this where the content update frequency is the mouse event frequency.

Comment: @MooseBoys: The link does not back your statement. Nowhere does it say, that GDI should not be used. As far as mouse updates: You get `WM_MOUSEMOVE` messages as often as you ask for them, and no more often. The frequency of `WM_MOUSEMOVE` messages is controlled by the application, not the hardware device.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103247/discussion-between-mooseboys-and-iinspectable).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you have a striking reason not to, rendering should always be performed in a `WM_PAINT` handler. A `WM_PAINT` message is generated on demand, if the update region is non-empty and there are no other higher priority messages in the message queue. This has two immediate consequences:

- Input messages are handled before (potentially costly) rendering happens. This leads to a more responsive UI.
- Multiple calls to `InvalidateRect` are coalesced into a single `WM_PAINT` message. This reduces overall cost of rendering.

The code you posted under *Version 2* is able to profit from the system provided optimizations.

A disadvantage of *Version 1* is, that whatever it renders to the screen will be overwritten, when the system decides to generate a `WM_PAINT` message. It is both more wasteful, and potentially doesn't render the desired result.

---

Not specifically asked in the question, but if you need higher-precision mouse move events than those coalesced into a single `WM_MOUSEMOVE` message, you can call [GetMouseMovePointsEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646259.aspx) to get up to 64 previous (intermediate) mouse pointer positions.